# Need to capture a radio button response using PHP into

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have created a html membership form but only the first section of the form is posting to my POSTgreSQL database.  The first section goes to member table and that is working fine except for a membership radio button.  The second section is suppose go to userprofile but nothing is posting.  I have verified that the table names match.  Here is my php code:

```
    <?php 
    //retrieve our DATA FROM POST
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];        
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $investor = $_Post['investor'];
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
    $Address1 = $_POST['Address1'];
    $Address2 = $_POST['Address2'];
    $City = $_POST['City'];
    $State = $_POST['State'];
    $Zip = $_POST['Zip'];
    $Telephone = $_POST['Telephone'];
    $Telephone2 = $_POST['Telephone2'];
    $host = "localhost";
    $database = "1234";
    $db_user = "1234";
    $db_pass = "password";

    $conn = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$database user=$db_user password=$db_pass")or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

 // Insert login info into members table
   pg_prepare($conn, "MyInsert", 'INSERT INTO members (username, password, email, salt, investor) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING id;');
   $makeitso = pg_execute($conn, "MyInsert", array($username, $password, $email, $salt, $investor));
   $row = pg_fetch_row($makeitso); // Get the return of the INSERT...RETURNING SQL as an array
   $login_id = $row['0']; // Get the first array object (should be the only one) indicating the id created by the INSERT

   // Insert personal info into userprofile table
   pg_prepare($conn, "MyInsert2", 'INSERT INTO userprofile ("FirstName", "LastName", "Address1", "Address2", "City", "State", "Zip", "Telephone", "Telephone2", login_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING id;');
   pg_execute($conn, "MyInsert2", array($FirstName, $LastName, $Address1, $Address2, $City, $State, $Zip, $Telephone, $Telephone2, $login_id));

   IF($investor = t)
{   
    header('Location: myaccount.html');
}
Else
{
header('Location: notqualified.html');
}
  ?>
```

Here is the main part of my html to include the radio button:

```
    <td><h3>Personal Information</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="FirstName">Legal First Name:</label><br>
                        <input name="FirstName" maxlength="25" type="text">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label><br>
                        <input name="LastName" maxlength="25" type="text">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
    **NOTE--GOES IN FOR EACH INPUT THEN HERE IS THE RADIO BUTTON:
    <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <input name="investor" value="t" onclick="strikeThrough('amnot', 'am');" type="radio">
                        <span id="am">
                            I have read and completely understand the<br>
                            <a href="#" onclick="showAIModal();return false;">definition of an Accredited Investor</a> and<br>
                            I am an Accredited Investor requesting<br>
                            additional information.
                        </span>
                    </td>
```

Comment: You're simply assuming all of those statements are going to work.  Always check return values for failures. *Never* assume success. Always assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise. –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio button has $_Post instead $_POST

Comment: thanks! that solved the issue of the investor not posting but I still cannot get the anything to userprofile table.  Any suggestions after looking at the code

Comment: Could be vals between " " causing error?, the first INSERT has not " "   but the second INSERT yes. You also can active PHP errors with ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

Answer (score 0):

If your radio button isn't selected then $_POST['investor doesn't exist at all, so:

```
if (isset($_POST['investor'])
    $investor = true;
else
    $investor = false;
```

By looking at your html, i'd say you should rather use a input type="checkbox" as it seems to be an agreement check...

Comment: there are two radio buttons and one has to be selected to submit.  they are registering in the database now but the userproflie is not at all.